# JQPlot Hide Lines from Legend Click

Tags: javascript, graph, show-hide, jqplot, legend

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamic Flot graph - show hide series by clicking on legend text or box on graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201911/dynamic-flot-graph-show-hide-series-by-clicking-on-legend-text-or-box-on-graph)

I am using JQPlot and I have a question about hiding lines if they have been clicked on in the legend.

Here is my code:

```
 var plotCustomerSurveyGraph = $.jqplot('CustomerSurveyLineGraph', [[0,1,3,2,3,0,1,3,1,2,3,1,2], [1,2,3,1,1,2,2,3,3,1,2,1,2], [1,2,3,4,4,3,2,2,1,4,3,2,2], [0,1,3,3,1,2,2,1,1,0,0,1,2],[2,2,3,3,4,4,0,2,0,1,1,3,3], [2,2,3,3,1,1,0,1,0,2,3,3,1], [1,3,1,4,3,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,1], [2,1,3,2,1,2,0,1,2,4,2,1,0]], 
{ 
            axes:
            {
                xaxis:
                {
                      label: "Date (Week)",
                      ticks: ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13']
                },
                yaxis:
                {
                    label: 'Rating',
                    labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                    ticks: ['0','1','2','3']
                }
            },
    title:'Customer Survey (Last 3 Months)',
            width: 480, height: 480,
            legend:{show:true, location: 'e', placement: 'outsideGrid'},
    seriesDefaults: 
    {
                rendererOptions: {smooth: true}
    },
    series:[ 
                {
                    lineWidth:1, 
                    label:'Staff Appearance',
                    markerOptions: { size:7, style:'dimaond' }
                }, 
                {
                    lineWidth:1, 
                    label:'Staff Product Knowledge',
                    markerOptions: { size: 7, style:"dimaond" }
                }, 
                {
                    lineWidth:1, 
                    label:'Staff Friendliness',
                    markerOptions: { size:7, style:"filledSquare" }
                }, 
                {
                    lineWidth:1, 
                    label:'Staff Wait Time Acceptable',
                    markerOptions: { size:7, style:"filledSquare" }
                }, 
                {
                    lineWidth:1, 
                    label:'Food Value For Money',
                    markerOptions: { size:7, style:"filledSquare" }
                }, 
                {
                    lineWidth:1, 
                    label:'Overall Quality of Meal',
                    markerOptions: { size:7, style:"filledSquare" }
                }, 
                {
                    lineWidth:1, 
                    label:'Cleanliness of the Premises',
                    markerOptions: { size:7, style:"filledSquare" }
                }, 
                {
                    lineWidth:1, 
                    label:'Ambience and Atmosphere of the Premises',
                    markerOptions: { size:7, style:"filledSquare" }
                }
                ]
    }
);
```

And here is an image of the graph:

[image]

Is it possible to enable a feature to hide/show the lines depending on whether they have been clicked in the legend? If so, can I please have some help to do this?

Thanks

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201911/dynamic-flot-graph-show-hide-series-by-clicking-on-legend-text-or-box-on-graph/14227287#14227287,  in it I put together a Demo of what you are asking.

Comment: This answer is for JQ FLOT, and not apply to JqPlot.

Answer (score 9):

Try this

Add `renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer` in your code

```
legend:{
                renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,
                show:true,
                location: 'e', 
                showSwatches: true,
                placement: 'outsideGrid'
            }
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/JWhmQ/1379/

Comment: And how it is possible to reload max value of yaxis after LegendRenderer?