# Update axes when toggling series jquery flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I have a chart with 5 series that I can toggle through the legend as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201911/dynamic-flot-graph-show-hide-series-by-clicking-on-legend-text-or-box-on-graph) But when toggling the series they get removed but the axis doesnt get updated. I have added setupGrid() after setData() and before draw() but with no result. So I thought that Flot still counts the hidden series, so I tried to go through the code and look for the setupGrid and in every series loop I added a check so that the loops continues if the line is hidden and that just messed up the whole calculation. Then I just added a check for it when calculating x/y max/min and that gave the same problem.

What should I do to make it calulate the axis correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, `flot` does not take into account the visibility of the series when calculating it's auto-scaling.  In version 0.8.1, the culprit is around line 1177, when it sets the `datamax`/`datamin` attributes.  It could skip the series if it's never going to be drawn:

```
if (s.lines.show == false &&
    s.points.show == false &&
    s.bars.show == false) continue;
```

**BUT**, I'd worry this would break plugins that introduce additional plot types.

---

**So instead**, I'd just mask the data off to make the auto-scaling work:

```
togglePlot = function(seriesIdx)
{
  var someData = somePlot.getData();  
  someData[seriesIdx].lines.show = !someData[seriesIdx].lines.show;  
  if (!someData[seriesIdx].lines.show){
      someData[seriesIdx].tempData = someData[seriesIdx].data;
      someData[seriesIdx].data = [];  // store old data and blank out real data
  }
  else
  {
      someData[seriesIdx].data = someData[seriesIdx].tempData; // restore real data
  }
  somePlot.setData(someData);
  somePlot.setupGrid();
  somePlot.draw();
}
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AcuC7/85/).